# Is there any terminology that refers to both lexis and grammar?

Tags: terminology

I wonder if there is any terminology that refers to a level of language consisting of lexis and grammar.

It would be nice to know it. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: In short: Linguistics.

Comment: In systemic functional linguistics (SFL), the term **lexicogrammar** is used a lot.

Comment: Thanks @jknappen-ReinstateMonica. I think your answer is better than the previous.